# Apply PHP script to a single text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I'm after a simple answer I think.

I have a text box called 'ref' on a page. 
When filled in and entered it takes the user to www.website.com/$ref.php.

I need their input to be uppercase to match the directory so I have added this code to change what they type.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val()
    $(this).val(val.toUpperCase())
 })
})
</script>
```

This works great but it is applied to all text boxes on the page.

How do I limit the script to text box 'ref' AND/OR is there a better way of achieving the same effect.

"if (textbox-name=ref) then apply script"

Thanks

Comment: You can select the textbox with jQuery: `$('#ref').val(valueFromAjax);` assuming the textbox has an ID set

Comment: or `document.getElementById("ref");` assumming also that your element has an ID ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery selector you already have:

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
```

Change it like this:

```
$('input[name="ref"]').keyup(function() {
```

that will select just that one text box and assign the keyup event to it.
**jQuery selectors work just like css selectors.**

However, if you want to insure that this is the only element that has this keyup function attached, then use an ID attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Select the input by id,

```
$("#ref").
```

Comment: Please consider improving this to a full answer. As it stands to day it's hard to understand the answer and the motivation behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is applying the JQuery code to all `input` elements. To single out just that one, apply an `id` to the textbox, e.g. `id="ref"`. Then you just reference it by `id` in your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ref").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val()
    $(this).val(val.toUpperCase())
  })
})
```

You should also read up on [JQuery selectors](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/).

Answer (score 0):

What way did you call this text box 'ref'? if you have class="ref" as an attribute to it, change the selector in jQuery to input.ref. If you have id="ref", change it to input#ref. But you can better do it in php anyway (with strtoupper)